# Changing where kitchen-vagrant downloads chef from

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm doing some Chef recipe testing using test-kitchen on vagrant virtuals.  Each time I run `kitchen test`, it is downloading a copy of the chef omnibus installer from the standard place (Amazon).  The problem is that I'm at home, and each of those downloads takes time, and adds to my monthly network usage.

Is there a way to configure test-kitchen / kitchen-vagrant / whatever so that the downloads come from a local cache?  If I set up a caching proxy webserver on my PC, can I get test-kitchen to configure the vagrant instance to use it for the chef downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the process is documented in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fnichol/7551540), but in short:

Use ERB in your `.kitchen.yml`:

```
<%
require 'socket'

def local_ip
  @local_ip ||= begin
    # turn off reverse DNS resolution temporarily
    orig, Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup, true

    UDPSocket.open do |s|
      s.connect '64.233.187.99', 1
      s.addr.last
    end
  ensure
    Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = orig
  end
end

def local_port ; 8123 ; end
def http_proxy_url ; "http://#{local_ip}:#{local_port}" ; end

def proxy_running?
  socket = TCPSocket.new(local_ip, local_port)
  true
rescue SocketError, Errno::ECONNREFUSED,
  Errno::EHOSTUNREACH, Errno::ENETUNREACH, IOError
  false
rescue Errno::EPERM, Errno::ETIMEDOUT
  false
ensure
  socket && socket.close
end
%>
---
<% if proxy_running? %>
driver:
  http_proxy: <%= http_proxy_url %>
  https_proxy: <%= http_proxy_url %>
  provision_command: "env http_proxy=<%= http_proxy_url %> bash -c 'curl -L http://www.getchef.com/chef/install.sh | bash'"

provisioner:
  chef_omnibus_url: http://www.getchef.com/chef/install.sh
<% end %>
```

The instructions for running a proxy use polipo, but you could use any caching proxy you would like.